# how to fix Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined in angular material data table?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to implemet angular material datatable.
I am able to implement basic table and filter functionality.

But i at the time of sort i am getting below error.

**Error:**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined
    at ListPostComponent.ngAfterViewInit (list-post.component.ts:53)
    at callHook (core.js:4708)
    at callHooks (core.js:4672)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4612)
    at refreshView (core.js:11969)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13256)
    at refreshView (core.js:11916)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13331)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11622)
    at refreshView (core.js:11945)
```

**Post model**

```
import {User} from '../user/user.model';

export class Post {
    id: number;
    created_by: number;
    created_on: string;
    is_published: boolean;
    is_delete: boolean;
    title: string;
    slug: string;
    sub_title: string;
    content: string;
    tags: Array<string>;
    user: User
}
```

**component.html**

In html i have used attribute `matSort and mat-sort-header`

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. ium">
</mat-form-field>
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">
        <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><a [routerLink]="['/users/view', row.id]" class="a-style">{{row.id}}</a>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Title Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Title</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.title}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Slug Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="slug">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Slug</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.slug}}</td>
        </ng-container>



        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

Here i imported `MatSort, MatTableDataSource` and also imported `MatSortModule` in app.module.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';

import { PostService } from '../../service/post/post.service';
import { Post } from './../../models/post/post.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-post',
  templateUrl: './list-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-post.component.css']
})
export class ListPostComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'title', 'slug'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Post>;

  constructor(
    private postService: PostService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllPosts();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  getAllPosts() {
    this.postService.getAllPost().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data['posts']);        
      }
    )
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

can any one guide me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? In Angular 9 {static: true} is removed from @ViewChild.

Comment: @RiadBaghbanli I am using angular 9. ok let me try

Comment: Also, move "this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;" to ngOnInit().

Comment: @RiadBaghbanli i tried by removing {static: true}. but still it is showing same error

Comment: @RiadBaghbanli i moved "this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;" to ngOnInit() but still it is showing same error

Comment: see the answer I posted. simple bug.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is dataSource is not initiated at the time you are trying to set sort property value.

Option 1: Fix the following line:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Post>;
```

to:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Post>();
```

Option 2: Set this.dataSource.sort right after setting the dataSource in getAllPosts:

```
  getAllPosts() {
    this.postService.getAllPost().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data['posts']);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;        
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: using `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Post>();` i am able to resolve the error. but sort functionality is not working

Comment: Move "this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;" back to ngAfterView for Option 1. You need to add this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = this.sortPosts; where sortPosts is defined as sortPosts( post: Post, property ); if custom sorting is needed. See https://material.angular.io/components/table/api

Comment: you don't have a method named "sort" defined in your code. you could add something like this: this.dataSource.sort((curr: any, next: any) => { return curr.name < next.name ? -1 : 1; });

Comment: @RiadBaghbanli i have tried with`this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (obj, property) => this.getProperty(obj, property);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;` but not working. is this code is correct ?

Comment: this.dataSource.sort() is not a function @Rick

Comment: @SangramBadi. I guess I'm not sure what it is then if it's not an array of objects. what type of data are you getting back? And if it's not an array, why are you trying to sort it?

Comment: I am getting Array as response. but `this.dataSource.sort((curr: any, next: any) => { return curr.name < next.name ? -1 : 1; }); ` is not a function

Comment: hmmm. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be.